# Querying string with apostrophe in Cloud Search

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have string `'Vick's'` that I need to pass to the cloud search using the API. But when I passing it to the API it throws an error. When I am using `'Vick&apos;s'` instead of `Vick's` as a search string it is not giving exact result. The search for on the other hand `'Vick%27s'` is working fine.

When I am in the Amazon and doing some searches there, they turn out fine for `"Vick's"` and `"Vick\'s"`. I am using Amazing Cloud Search wrapper, which written in C#.

My question is: How to querying string with apostrophe in cloud search?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to prepend your ' with a slash (\'). And if you're using Java, and you're doing replaceAll, you'll need to do something along the lines of .replaceAll("'", "\\'") (4 slashes - even though only 2 appear here!).

Hope it helps!